# Twin Peaks general explanation

Tags: twin-peaks

I just finished watching *Twin Peaks: The Return*. I've also watched (quite a while ago the first and second seasons, and also *Fire Walk With Me*). So, after watching everything I'm completely lost. Do you know any site with a complete and detailed explanation of the events on the show?

Comment: Look, asking for recommendations is not on-topic here. However, we happen to be one such site with users who will be able to _provide_ these detailed explanations for you, right here. So please think of the problems or questions you have, and ask them here (in a new post per question). Good luck.

Comment: Roughly speaking, I think Twin Peaks isn’t primarily a story; it’s intended more to provoke thoughts and feelings than to convey specific ideas. Of course, it can be illuminating to see what other people got out of it. Here’s [some thoughts about *The Return*](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2017/sep/06/twin-peaks-was-this-the-long-perfect-goodbye-from-david-lynch) from The Guardian.

Comment: Isn’t there also at least one book? Secret Diary of Laura Palmer